# AJAX callback failing in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax

The page contains accordion control which expands and contract on clicks. When it expands, it's supposed to show the records from the database. It works fine when I first open the page. But it fails on refresh.
This working fine in IE, Its the problem with Firefox only. On Refresh its failing in Firefox.
I tried giving "hPanelLoaded" a value of "FALSE" on page load. Still its notworking.
It seems on refresh FF is not able to get the value of "hPanelLoaded" and it says "$("hPanelLoaded") is null".

here is the Page structure.
MainPage.aspx  is calling Control > hPanelLoaded.ascx  is calling >  hPanelLoaded.js.

Any idea what mistake I am doing.

Here is the code

@@@@@@@@@@  this is in hPanelLoaded.ascx. @@@@@@@@@@@

```
<input type="hidden" id="hPanelLoaded" />
```

@@@@@@@@@@  this is in hPanelLoaded.js. @@@@@@@@@@@

```
function loadPanel1() {
    try {
        if ($('hPanelLoaded').value != 'TRUE') {
            grdarts.callback();
            $('hPanelLoaded').value = 'TRUE'
        }
     // else {
              //  alert('INSIDE ELSE');
              //  $('hPanelLoaded').value = 'FALSE';
           // }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Your selector should be

```
$('#hPanelLoaded')
```

since you are selecting by id (note the addition of the `#`)

Comment: But its working first time when the page loads. Its not working when I refresh the page. If what you said is correct it should not work in the first place right?

Comment: `$('hPanelLoaded')` is trying to find a `<hPanelLoaded>` element in your DOM, which I'd assume doesn't exist, so its value won't be `'TRUE'`, which is why `grdarts.callback()` gets fired. If it works on load but not on refresh, there are other issues with your code.

Comment: After updating the code , I am getting the error. TypeError: $("#hPanelLoaded") is null

Comment: are you sure jQuery is loaded? that should never be null, it could be an empty array, but not null

Comment: I dont think we are using jquery. I didnt find anywhere on the page

Comment: oh, well that's entirely different then. Your code is trying to use jQuery (or similar library), and you tagged your question with jQuery.  Try using `document.getElementById('hPanelLoaded').value`